# Как сделать notification постоянным?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, уведомления

Здравствуйте. Не получается notifications сделать постоянным. Через определенное время время он скрывается. Пробовал и время выставить больше и убрать его, но все равно уведомление закрывается через определенное количество времени.

```
 function notifyMe(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
      body: theBody,
      icon: theIcon
  }
  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
  setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 30000); 
}
```

Пробовал и другими методами, все равно также.

```
var message_notification = new Notification("Data");
setTimeout(function(){
    message_notification.close();
}, 30000);
```

Время увеличить не получается, браузер игнорирует это.

Comment: Вроде как нельзя поставить больше, по умолчанию каждый браузер сам закрывает оповещение гдето через 4-5 секунд, можно разве что раньше закрыть его.

Comment: А как тогда М.Видео делает так, чтобы эти уведомления висели по 30 минут и больше? Попробуйте у них сделать так. У цветочной компании тоже так, долго висит.

Comment: @Moonvvell И я делал уведомление максимум на 19 секунд, потом оно закрывается. А вот больше не могу.

Comment: Можно добавить свой ServiceWorker и в нем закрывать уведомление когда хотите, Потому что вроде как стандартный воркер закрывает уведомление все таки сам. Но поэтому и пишу это в комментариях т.к. кто знает, может сейчас уже чтото поменялось и есть возможность просто и легко настроить это все а я несу чушь )) https://mobiforge.com/design-development/web-push-notifications тут почитайте к примеру

Comment: ServiceWorker работает только в пару браузеров, а нужна поддержка хотя бы стандартных браузеров(chrome, firefox,opera,safari).
Вот: "Поддерживается браузерами Firefox 43+ и Chrome 42+ на десктопах"